# Scalebreakstyle not working in Chart

Tags: c#, charts

My chart has a Datetime type X Axis and Double type Y Axis. I am trying to use the following code to insert the scalebreakstyle feature but it is not working. Does anyone have sample code for it. I was trying the web.UI code but did not work. Also I set the color of 2 series the same it keeps making them different.
/

```
/ Enable scale breaks.
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;

   // Show scale break if more than 25% of the chart is empty space.
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.CollapsibleSpaceThreshold = 25;

   // Set the line width of the scale break.
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth = 2;

   // Set the color of the scale break.
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor = Color.Red;

   // If all data points are significantly far from zero, the chart will calculate the scale minimum value.
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.StartFromZero = StartFromZero.Auto;

   // Set the spacing gap between the lines of the scale break (as a percentage of the Y-axis).
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 2;
```

www.tinypic.com/r/6e2c83/5

Answer (score 2):

Scale breaks will not work under a wide array of conditions.  According to the documentation any of the following causes scale breaks to be "not supported", which I have found means they will not work at all or they will warp your graph in weird ways

•Pie, doughnut, funnel, pyramid, radial or any stacked chart types are used.

•Custom intervals for labels, tick marks or grid lines are enabled.

•The minimum or maximum value for the axis is set.

•Custom labels are used.

•A logarithmic Y-axis is specified.

•Axis views on the Y-axis, which include scrolling and zooming, are used.

•3-D charts are used.

It looks like you maybe have a custome x axis label which would cause the scale break to fail.